# Color heatmap in different colors by column in dataframe

Tags: colors, seaborn, heatmap

I have a dataframe which i'm trying to plot in a heatmap.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(10, 5)),
                  columns=['1', '2','3','4','5'])

cluster = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5]
df['cluster'] = cluster

x_axis_labels = []
for i in range(1, 6):
    x_axis_labels.append(i)
        
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 10))
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
np_smooth = gaussian_filter(df, sigma=0.75)
sns.heatmap(np_smooth, cmap="YlGnBu",
            xticklabels=x_axis_labels,
            yticklabels=False, cbar=False)
plt.show()
```

And this is the output:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ8Id.png)

Each row of the heatmap represents a row in the df. I would like to color each cluster in a different color.
like in this photo:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Ic5.png)
I've added the following code but it gives me an error. Would be happy for some help!

The additional code:

```
cmaps = {'1': 'Blues_r', '2': 'Greens_r', '3': 'Blues_r', '4': 'Greens_r', '5': 'Blues_r', '6': 'Greens_r', '7': 'Blues_r','0': 'Greens_r'}
    
for clus, cmap in cmaps.items():
   mask = df.apply(lambda x: x if x['cluster'] == int(clus) else 0, result_type='broadcast', 
   axis=1).eq(0)
        
   sns.heatmap(np_smooth, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, xticklabels=x_axis_labels, yticklabels=False, 
   cbar=False, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numexpr\necompiler.py in evaluate(ex, local_dict, global_dict, out, order, casting, **kwargs)
    826     try:
--> 827         compiled_ex = _numexpr_cache[numexpr_key]
    828     except KeyError:

KeyError: ('a_value | b_value', (('optimization', 'aggressive'), ('truediv', True)), (('a_value', <class 'numpy.float64'>), ('b_value', <class 'bool'>)))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-191-2f3e7e4bc9aa> in cluster_heatmap(df, plot_name, base_num)
     24         ).eq(0)
     25         # plot masked heatmap on reusable ax
---> 26         sns.heatmap(np_smooth, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, ax=ax, xticklabels=x_axis_labels, yticklabels=False, cbar=False)
     27 
     28 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     44             )
     45         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
     47     return inner_f
     48 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py in heatmap(data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt, annot_kws, linewidths, linecolor, cbar, cbar_kws, cbar_ax, square, xticklabels, yticklabels, mask, ax, **kwargs)
    540     plotter = _HeatMapper(data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt,
    541                           annot_kws, cbar, cbar_kws, xticklabels,
--> 542                           yticklabels, mask)
    543 
    544     # Add the pcolormesh kwargs here

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py in __init__(self, data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, annot, fmt, annot_kws, cbar, cbar_kws, xticklabels, yticklabels, mask)
    107 
    108         # Validate the mask and convet to DataFrame
--> 109         mask = _matrix_mask(data, mask)
    110 
    111         plot_data = np.ma.masked_where(np.asarray(mask), plot_data)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\matrix.py in _matrix_mask(data, mask)
     86     # This works around an issue where `plt.pcolormesh` doesn't represent
     87     # missing data properly
---> 88     mask = mask | pd.isnull(data)
     89 
     90     return mask

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in f(self, other, axis, level, fill_value)
   2021             # Another DataFrame
   2022             pass_op = op if should_series_dispatch(self, other, op) else na_op
-> 2023             return self._combine_frame(other, pass_op, fill_value, level)
   2024         elif isinstance(other, ABCSeries):
   2025             # For these values of `axis`, we end up dispatching to Series op,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _combine_frame(self, other, func, fill_value, level)
   5086         if ops.should_series_dispatch(this, other, func):
   5087             # iterate over columns
-> 5088             return ops.dispatch_to_series(this, other, _arith_op)
   5089         else:
   5090             result = _arith_op(this.values, other.values)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in dispatch_to_series(left, right, func, str_rep, axis)
   1155         raise NotImplementedError(right)
   1156 
-> 1157     new_data = expressions.evaluate(column_op, str_rep, left, right)
   1158 
   1159     result = left._constructor(new_data, index=left.index, copy=False)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, use_numexpr, **eval_kwargs)
    206     use_numexpr = use_numexpr and _bool_arith_check(op_str, a, b)
    207     if use_numexpr:
--> 208         return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)
    209     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
    210 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b, truediv, reversed, **eval_kwargs)
    121 
    122     if result is None:
--> 123         result = _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
    124 
    125     return result

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)
     66         _store_test_result(False)
     67     with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
---> 68         return op(a, b)
     69 
     70 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in column_op(a, b)
   1133         def column_op(a, b):
   1134             return {i: func(a.iloc[:, i], b.iloc[:, i])
-> 1135                     for i in range(len(a.columns))}
   1136 
   1137     elif isinstance(right, ABCSeries) and axis == "columns":

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
   1133         def column_op(a, b):
   1134             return {i: func(a.iloc[:, i], b.iloc[:, i])
-> 1135                     for i in range(len(a.columns))}
   1136 
   1137     elif isinstance(right, ABCSeries) and axis == "columns":

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _arith_op(left, right)
   5082             # left._binop(right, func, fill_value=fill_value)
   5083             left, right = ops.fill_binop(left, right, fill_value)
-> 5084             return func(left, right)
   5085 
   5086         if ops.should_series_dispatch(this, other, func):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py in na_op(x, y)
   1999 
   2000         try:
-> 2001             result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y, **eval_kwargs)
   2002         except TypeError:
   2003             result = masked_arith_op(x, y, op)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, use_numexpr, **eval_kwargs)
    206     use_numexpr = use_numexpr and _bool_arith_check(op_str, a, b)
    207     if use_numexpr:
--> 208         return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)
    209     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)
    210 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py in _evaluate_numexpr(op, op_str, a, b, truediv, reversed, **eval_kwargs)
    112                                              'b_value': b_value},
    113                                  casting='safe', truediv=truediv,
--> 114                                  **eval_kwargs)
    115         except ValueError as detail:
    116             if 'unknown type object' in str(detail):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numexpr\necompiler.py in evaluate(ex, local_dict, global_dict, out, order, casting, **kwargs)
    827         compiled_ex = _numexpr_cache[numexpr_key]
    828     except KeyError:
--> 829         compiled_ex = _numexpr_cache[numexpr_key] = NumExpr(ex, signature, **context)
    830     kwargs = {'out': out, 'order': order, 'casting': casting,
    831               'ex_uses_vml': ex_uses_vml}

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numexpr\necompiler.py in NumExpr(ex, signature, **kwargs)
    624 
    625     context = getContext(kwargs, frame_depth=1)
--> 626     threeAddrProgram, inputsig, tempsig, constants, input_names = precompile(ex, signature, context)
    627     program = compileThreeAddrForm(threeAddrProgram)
    628     return interpreter.NumExpr(inputsig.encode('ascii'),

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numexpr\necompiler.py in precompile(ex, signature, context)
    569         ast = ASTNode('op', value='copy', astKind=ex.astKind, children=(ast,))
    570 
--> 571     ast = typeCompileAst(ast)
    572 
    573     aliases = collapseDuplicateSubtrees(ast)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numexpr\necompiler.py in typeCompileAst(ast)
    212                 raise NotImplementedError(
    213                     "couldn't find matching opcode for '%s'"
--> 214                     % (ast.value + '_' + retsig + basesig))
    215         # First just cast constants, then cast variables if necessary:
    216         for i, (have, want) in enumerate(zip(basesig, sig)):

NotImplementedError: couldn't find matching opcode for 'or_bdb'
```

Comment: please provide all data as text, or better as arrays/DataFrames

Comment: What do you mean? i should write the dataframe as a code?

Comment: Yes, your question should be fully reproducible (ideally using a small example). If one can just copy/paste/execute your code, it's much easier to be able to fix it.

Comment: it would also help to provide a schematic of what you expect ;)

Comment: I've just added

Comment: You could try to convert the mask from dataframe to a numpy array via `mask = df.apply(....).eq(0).values`.  You might want to add all the imports to your code to make it easier to reproduce.  Is this `numexpr` a library you explicitly include? Also note that you might want to exclude the clusters array both from `np_smooth` as from `mask`.

Answer (score 0):

A dataframe as mask seems to give some errors. You could use `mask.values` to just grab the values.

The example code below makes the following changes:

- the columns of the dataframe are changed from integer to float
- the clusters column is left out for the `gaussian_filter` and for the `mask`
- the mask is calculated by repeating the mask value for the clusters column
- the directionary for the colormaps now uses numbers as keys

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10, 5)).astype(float),
                  columns=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
cluster = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
df['cluster'] = cluster

x_axis_labels = range(1, 6)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 10))
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter

np_smooth = gaussian_filter(df[df.columns[:-1]], sigma=0.75)

cmaps = {1: 'Reds_r', 2: 'Greys_r', 3: 'Blues_r', 4: 'Greens_r', 5: 'Purples_r', 6: 'Greens_r', 7: 'Blues_r',
         0: 'Greens_r'}
for clus, cmap in cmaps.items():
     mask = np.repeat((df['cluster'] != int(clus)).values.reshape(-1, 1), len(df.columns) - 1, 1)
     if not mask.all():
          sns.heatmap(np_smooth, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, xticklabels=x_axis_labels, yticklabels=False,
                      cbar=False, ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap with different colormaps]

PS: To have consistent color ranges, you might use `vmin=np_smooth.min(), vmax=np_smooth.max()` in the calls to  `sns.heatmap()`.

Comment: WOW Thanks!! It works great! But the only problem is that is gives me the inverted colors. I mean white for 1.0 and dark for 0.0 value. How can i transform/invert the colors so that white will be for 0 and dark for 1?

Comment: You'd need to remove the `_r` part of the colormap names. `Reds` is the colormap in its usual order from light to dark while `Reds_r` has the reversed colors.